# Is there an autocomplete for Dr. Racket?

Tags: autocomplete, ide, racket, dr.racket

I usually use Sublime text editor and gnome terminal to edit and run my programs. Due to educational purposes, I am using the IDE Dr. Racket.

I could not find an autocomplete feature to use while typing. I checked this out on google and at Dr. Racket's menu.

For instance, if I am calling a function already defined I would like to *accelerate* the process of typing the functions name.
I have tried using <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, but it does not work as an autocomplete for variables and procedures already defined.

---

***Edit***

@Sylwester, look, I tried that with a previous defined function, named square. It did not work:[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer that I don't know which dictionary it uses and it certainly doesn't pick up on user created procedures like you `square` even after RUN/Syntax check.

Answer (score 21):

[image: Image of list of matched]

## Linux and Windows

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

## Mac OSX

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

The last "key" might not be a button on its own and if that's so it needs to be the combination to make a `/`. eg. on my norwegian keyboard its 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> since <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> makes a `/`.

I have no idea where it gets it's matches from since I see it finds `fold` even when it is not called that in `#lang racket`. It does not seem to catch user procedures either.

This answer is based on information from a [racket mailing list entry](https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2011-January/043605.html) from 2011. It's not documented in [DrRacket shotcuts](https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html) page so it might not be officially supported.

Comment: IIRC, it gets it from the bindings brought in from other files. But I've honestly found this auto complete to be _really_ slow and not worth using.

Answer (score 7):

On top of the default autocomplete, there are various other options:

- The [`drcomplete`](https://github.com/yjqww6/drcomplete/blob/master/README.md) package provides several autocomplete features,
- The [`quickscript-extra`](https://github.com/Metaxal/quickscript-extra) package contains the `dynamic-abbrev` script (autocomplete based on the contents of the file) and `complete-word` script (completion based on a given dictionary),
- The [`quickscript-competition-2020`](https://github.com/Quickscript-Competiton/July2020entries/) package contains the `fishy-completion` script (lexical-based completion).

For the latter 2, you get scripts entries in the `Scripts` menu in DrRacket, plus default keybindings that can be changed by editing the scripts. (Also note that the other scripts installed at the same time can be deactivated from the `Scripts|Manage|Disable scripts…` menu.)

Comment: Since Racket isn’t statically typed, do these just suggest everything in scope or can they somehow figure out which possibilities would actually work in context?

Comment: @joseph As mention in the answer, `fishy-completion` is using lexical information. `dynamic-abbrev` is based on the contents of the file, but not the lexical context, while `complete-word` is based on a static dictionary.  For `DrComplete`, it's complicated --- see the [README](https://github.com/yjqww6/drcomplete/blob/master/README.md)